# Assigning indexes to buttons C#

Tags: c#

I am working on an application for WP8, in my code I want to assign indexes to buttons like in arrays. Reason is that I want to operate buttons with buttons (i.e one button that is pressed activate other buttons)

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace test2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        } 
        public class LEDButton : Button
        {
            public const int LEDWidth = 50;
            public const int LEDHeight = 30;
            public LEDButton()
            {
                BackColor = Color.Tan;//inner color
                //BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 64, 0);
                ForeColor = Color.Yellow;//outline
                FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;//Button style
                Size = new Size(LEDWidth, LEDHeight);
                UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LEDButton[,] b = new LEDButton[4, 4];
            for (int y = 0; y < b.GetUpperBound(0); y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < b.GetUpperBound(1); x++)
                {
                    b[y, x] = new LEDButton()
                    {
                        //put button properties here
                        Name = "button" + y.ToString() + x.ToString(),//String.Format("Button{0}{1}", y, x),
                        TabIndex = 10 * y + x,
                        Text = y.ToString() + x.ToString(),
                        Location = new Point(LEDButton.LEDWidth * x + 20, LEDButton.LEDHeight * y + 20)
                    };
                   // b[y, x].Click += button_Click;
                }
            }
            // add buttons to controls
            for (int y = 0; y < b.GetUpperBound(0); y++)
                for (int x = 0; x < b.GetUpperBound(1); x++)
                   this.Controls.Add(b[y, x]); 
        }
    }

}
```

---

Comment: You didn't explain the problem you are having...

Comment: Actually I am trying to say that I need direct access to buttons, can we achieve it?

Comment: I am confused. Is it `WP8` or `WinForms` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--- loop ---
Button abc = new Button();
abc.Name = loopCounter.ToString();
--- loop ---
```

This will help you to assigning indexes,
Don't use array of Button, it is useless!

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your question properly, you should rely on an array of delegates. Here you have a correction of your code assigning dynamically 4 different methods to 4 different buttons:

```
namespace test2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public delegate void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e);
        public static button_click[] clickMethods = new button_click[4];
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public class LEDButton : Button
        {
            public const int LEDWidth = 50;
            public const int LEDHeight = 30;
            public LEDButton()
            {
                BackColor = Color.Tan;//inner color
                //BackColor = Color.FromArgb(0, 64, 0);
                ForeColor = Color.Yellow;//outline
                FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Popup;//Button style
                Size = new Size(LEDWidth, LEDHeight);
                UseVisualStyleBackColor = false;
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            clickMethods[0] = buttonGeneric_Click_1;
            clickMethods[1] = buttonGeneric_Click_2;
            clickMethods[2] = buttonGeneric_Click_3;
            clickMethods[3] = buttonGeneric_Click_4;
        }
        private void buttonGeneric_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void buttonGeneric_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void buttonGeneric_Click_3(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void buttonGeneric_Click_4(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LEDButton[,] b = new LEDButton[4, 4];
            for (int y = 0; y < b.GetUpperBound(0); y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < b.GetUpperBound(1); x++)
                {
                    b[y, x] = new LEDButton()
                    {
                        //put button properties here
                        Name = "button" + y.ToString() + x.ToString(),//String.Format("Button{0}{1}", y, x),
                        TabIndex = 10 * y + x,
                        Text = y.ToString() + x.ToString(),
                        Location = new Point(LEDButton.LEDWidth * x + 20, LEDButton.LEDHeight * y + 20)
                    };

                    if (y <= 3)
                    {
                        b[y, x].Click += new System.EventHandler(clickMethods[y]); 
                    }
                }
            }
            // add buttons to controls
            for (int y = 0; y < b.GetUpperBound(0); y++)
                for (int x = 0; x < b.GetUpperBound(1); x++)
                    this.Controls.Add(b[y, x]);
        }
    }
}
```